# Can I generate arbitrary strings, and avoid repeating specifications in QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Given

```
data MyType = MyType ...

makeMyType :: String -> String -> String -> MyType
-- ...

type StringThing = String
```

where the strings that `makeMyType` expects are (respectively):

- a `-` delimited string of some custom strings (e.g., `"Hilary-Jeb-David-Charles"`),
- a string of 4 capital letters, and
- a `.` delimited string of integers between 1 and 26, each padded with a zero to two characters (e.g., `"04.23.11.09"`)

I can use [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) to generate adequate test cases with something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}
import Test.QuickCheck
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Text.Printf (printf)

-- This really should be an arbitrary string of random length in some range
instance Arbitrary StringThing where
        arbitrary = elements ["FUSHFJSHF","KLSJDHFLSKJDHFLSKJDFHLSKJDHFLSKJOIWURURW","GHSHDHUUUHHHA"]

instance Arbitrary MyType where
        arbitrary = do
                -- This repetition feels unnecessary
                w1 <- elements ['A'..'Z']
                w2 <- elements ['A'..'Z']
                w3 <- elements ['A'..'Z']
                w4 <- elements ['A'..'Z']
                c1 <- elements someListOfCustomStuff
                c2 <- elements someListOfCustomStuff
                c3 <- elements someListOfCustomStuff
                c4 <- elements someListOfCustomStuff
                r1 <- choose (1,26)
                r2 <- choose (1,26)
                r3 <- choose (1,26)
                r4 <- choose (1,26)
                return $ makeMyType (intercalate "-" [c4,c3,c2,c1])
                                    [w1,w2,w3,w4]
                                    (intercalate "." $ (printf "%02d") <$> ([r1,r2,r3,r4] :: [Int]))

prop_SomeProp :: MyType -> StringThing -> Bool
prop_SomeProp mt st = ...
```

But `StringThing` really should take on arbitrary strings of capital letters of random length within some range, and the repetition of the same specification for all the `w...`s, `c..`s, and `r....`s seems unnecessary.

Is there a way in QuickCheck to:

1. generate random strings with length within some bounds, restricted to certain characters, and
2. "share" a specification using `elements` or `choose` among multiple values?

Comment: in order to generate `[w1, ..., w4]`, you may use [`vectorOf  4 (elements ['A'..'Z'])`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:vectorOf) instead of `w1 <- ...`

Comment: `vectorOf` is a synonym for `replicateM` which is the more general combinator. Not sure how it snuck in (does it date from a time before QC had a `Monad` instance?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Haskell is great at being able to factor things out! You can certainly name and share subexpressions like `elements ['A'..'Z']`

```
capitals = elements ['A'..'Z']

instance Arbitrary StringThing where
        arbitrary = do
          l <- choose (1,50) -- this is your string length
          replicateM l capitals
```

And for your MyType, you can also use replicateM quite a lot:

```
instance Arbitrary MyType where
        arbitrary = do
                ws <- replicateM 4 capitals
                cs <- replicateM 4 (elements someListOfCustomStuff)
                rs <- replicateM 4 (choose (1,26))
                return $ makeMyType (intercalate "-" cs)
                                    ws
                                    (intercalate "." $ (printf "%02d") <$> (rs :: [Int]))
```

Comment: Doh! — I forgot all about `replicateM`!